# Minimum Curvature Gridding in R or QGIS?

Tags: r, geospatial, qgis

I'm looking for a way to grid oceanographic spatial data using Minimum Curvature.  It can be done in Surfer, but i'm look for OpenSource methods.  Have looked in R and QGIS but no joy.  Perhaps is buried in an R package somewhere? Can't see it in the 'spatial' package. Had no luck finding in GRASS either.  Any ideas?

Thanks,
PB

Comment: Got an online reference to what the "Minimum Curvature" thing is in your context?

Comment: Hmm okay, its an interpolation procedure like kriging or inverse distance weighting. https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-February/304988.html didn't get an answer :(

Comment: Hi Spacedman, yes, that was my request from a year ago.  now I'm more familiar with the topic, but still haven't found a solution.  Unfortunately I wouldn't even know how to begin to program it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

How about Tps from the fields package? It fits thin plate splines which might be equivalent to minimum curvature...

Answer (score 0):

Look at [surfit](http://surfit.sf.net) - result is comparable with MINC. I can say more - the only difference is that MINC have special condition on the grid boundary, instead of surfit.